# How to chenge Alert Button font in Android

Tags: javascript, java, android

I Have a Alert like this

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setTitle("Exit Confirmation")
.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit?")
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // continue with delete
    }
 })
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // do nothing
    }
 })
.show();
```

I want to change Button text of this alert.
Suppose android.R.string.yes is "I Do" and android.R.string.no is "I Don't"
Now I want to set comic.tft to it.
Please help...

Comment: just use your own strings from **String.xml**. Instead of **android.R.string.yes** use **R.string.own_string**

Answer (score 1):

For the font, after alert.show(), you can use:

```
Button btnPositive = alert.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
btnPositive.setTypeFace(myTypeFace);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.about)
```

in string.xml

```
<string name="about">I do</string>
<string name="aboutno">I don't</string>
```

Code:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setTitle("Exit Confirmation")
.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit?")
.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.about), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // continue with delete
    }
 })
.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.aboutno), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // do nothing
    }
 })
.show();
```